# Undeclared identifier 'ShowMessage' in Delphi 10

Tags: delphi

Ι am encountering an error in this code:

```pascal
Result := TempStr;
ShowMessage('test');
```

> Undeclared identifier 'ShowMessage'

Any ideas what I am doing wrong?

Comment: Please note that Delphi 2010 and Delphi 10 are two different versions. Delphi 10 is much newer than Delphi 2010.

Comment: (...even though one might think that Delphi 10 is 2000 years older...)

Answer (score 7):

If you look at the documentation, you'll see that the [`ShowMessage`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/en/Vcl.Dialogs.ShowMessage) function is found in the [`Dialogs`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/en/Vcl.Dialogs) unit.

Therefore, to use the `ShowMessage` function in a program or unit, you need to make sure to include the `Dialogs` unit in an appropriate [`uses`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/en/Programs_and_Units_(Delphi)) clause.

The `Dialogs` unit is by default included in GUI forms (both VCL and FMX), so most likely you are creating a new, non-form unit in a GUI application or developing a console application. In either case, you must add the unit yourself.

Here is a console example:

```pascal
program Error;

{$APPTYPE CONSOLE}

{$R *.res}

uses
  SysUtils;

begin
  ShowMessage('Test');
end.
```

becomes

```pascal
program Solution;

{$APPTYPE CONSOLE}

{$R *.res}

uses
  SysUtils, Dialogs;

begin
  ShowMessage('Test');
end.
```

Comment: And if you are using a modern version of Delphi, you may need to write `Vcl.Dialogs` instead of `Dialogs`, depending on your project settings.

Comment: Thanks a lot, it was really helpfull your answer

Comment: @yannis_kal: No problem! :)